# Input field with datepicker doesn't appear in Chrome or Edge

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, datepicker

Some Chrome or Edge users can’t see input fields with datepicker on my website.

I don’t know why my website doesn’t show up input field for some user.

I have changed datepicker from ‘fengyuanchen/datepicker’ to ‘air-datepicker’.
but, this problem isn’t solved.
I need help.

Capture
[Good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWb9V.png)
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpykG.png)

```
<div class="form-content">
        <div class="icon-left ui-datepicker default-input-client">
        <input name="deadline" readonly="readonly" type="text" class="theme-client" style="width: 240px;" placeholder="가능 일자 선택" data-toggle="datepicker">
        <i><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="14" height="14" viewBox="0 0 14 14"><g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"><path d="M0 0h14v14H0z"></path><rect width="12.8" height="11.8" x=".6" y="1.6" stroke="#9E9E9E" stroke-width="1.2" rx="2"></rect><path stroke="#9E9E9E" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="1.2" d="M.5 5.8h13M4 1V0M10 0v1"></path></g></svg></i>
        </div>
</div>
<script>
var startDate = $.getDate(14);
$.createDatePicker('[data-toggle="datepicker"]', {startDate: startDate, minDate: 0, maxDate: 14, theme: 'client'});
</script>
```

createDatepicker in air-datepicker.js

```
;(function () {
$.getDate = function (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
    return date;
};

$.createDatePicker = function (selector, options) {
    var defaults = {
        language: {
            days: ['일요일', '월요일', '화요일', '수요일', '목요일', '금요일', '토요일'],
            daysShort: ['일', '월', '화', '수', '목', '금', '토'],
            daysMin: ['일', '월', '화', '수', '목', '금', '토'],
            months: ['1월', '2월', '3월', '4월', '5월', '6월', '7월', '8월', '9월', '10월', '11월', '12월'],
            monthsShort: ['1월', '2월', '3월', '4월', '5월', '6월', '7월', '8월', '9월', '10월', '11월', '12월'],
            today: '오늘',
            clear: '취소',
            dateFormat: 'yyyy년 mm월 dd일',
            firstDay: 0
        },
        startDate: new Date(),
        minDate: '',
        maxDate: '',
        autoClose: true,
        toggleSelected: false,
        showOtherMonths: false,
        showOtherYears: false,
        selectOtherMonths: false,
        selectOtherYears: false,
        moveToOtherMonthsOnSelect: false,
        moveToOtherYearsOnSelect: false,
        prevHtml: '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="28" height="28" viewBox="0 0 28 28">\n' +
            '    <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">\n' +
            '        <g>\n' +
            '            <g>\n' +
            '                <g>\n' +
            '                    <g>\n' +
            '                        <g>\n' +
            '                            <g>\n' +
            '                                <g transform="translate(-829 -17387) translate(120 160) translate(0 16300) translate(0 468) translate(692 401) translate(0 41) rotate(-90 31 14)">\n' +
            '                                    <rect width="28" height="28" rx="2"/>\n' +
            '                                    <g stroke="#616161" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="1.2">\n' +
            '                                        <path d="M0 0L6 6 12 0" transform="translate(8 11) rotate(-180 6 3)"/>\n' +
            '                                    </g>\n' +
            '                                </g>\n' +
            '                            </g>\n' +
            '                        </g>\n' +
            '                    </g>\n' +
            '                </g>\n' +
            '            </g>\n' +
            '        </g>\n' +
            '    </g>\n' +
            '</svg>\n',
        nextHtml: '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="28" height="28" viewBox="0 0 28 28">\n' +
            '    <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">\n' +
            '        <g>\n' +
            '            <g>\n' +
            '                <g>\n' +
            '                    <g>\n' +
            '                        <g>\n' +
            '                            <g>\n' +
            '                                <g transform="translate(-1081 -17026) translate(120 160) translate(0 16300) translate(0 468) translate(692 40) translate(0 41) matrix(0 -1 -1 0 297 45)">\n' +
            '                                    <rect width="28" height="28" rx="2"/>\n' +
            '                                    <g stroke="#616161" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="1.2">\n' +
            '                                        <path d="M0 0L6 6 12 0" transform="translate(8 11) rotate(-180 6 3)"/>\n' +
            '                                    </g>\n' +
            '                                </g>\n' +
            '                            </g>\n' +
            '                        </g>\n' +
            '                    </g>\n' +
            '                </g>\n' +
            '            </g>\n' +
            '        </g>\n' +
            '    </g>\n' +
            '</svg>\n',
        onSelect: function (formattedDates, dates, that) {
            $(that.el).change();
        }
    };

    var opts = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

    if (opts.minDate === '' || opts.minDate === undefined) opts.minDate = ''
    else opts.minDate = $.getDate(opts.minDate)

    if (opts.maxDate === '' || opts.maxDate === undefined) opts.maxDate = ''
    else opts.maxDate = $.getDate(opts.maxDate)

    return $(selector).datepicker(opts);
}})();
```

Comment: Could you provide your current code?

Comment: I added my code. I use air-datepicker. 
I share air-datepicker github. https://github.com/t1m0n/air-datepicker